# Return next object in array

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I expect this code to output the name of the current and of the next dimension member where next is defined by the absorder attribute of each dimension member.

```
<% @dimension_members.each do |dm| %>
    <p><%= dm.name %></p>
    <p><%= DimensionMember.where(:absorder => dm.absorder+1).name %></p>
<% end %>
```

Instead the code returns the name of the current dimension member, and then "DimensionMember" for every next member.

The following code produces `#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x3f952e0>`:

```
<% @dimension_members.each do |dm| %>
    <p><%= dm.name %></p>
    <p><%= DimensionMember.where(:absorder => dm.absorder+1) %></p>
<% end %>
```

I have to imagine there's a much easier way to return the next member in an array, but I can't quite get it to work. I've tried the following code with this idea in mind, but it produces `#<DimensionMember:0x3f943f8>`:

```
<% @dimension_members.each do |dm| %>
    <p><%= dm.name %></p>
    <p><%= @dimension_members[dm.absorder+1] %></p>
<% end %>
```

Lastly, I've tried this:

```
<% @dimension_members.each do |dm| %>
    <p><%= dm.name %></p>
    <p><%= @dimension_members[dm.absorder+1].name %></p>
<% end %>
```

But this returns the error:

`undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`

So how would I get the next dimension_member where next is defined by the particular attribute absorder?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting strange results is because the where query is returning a relation/collection and not a single object. You just need to get the first object from the query with:

```
DimensionMember.where(:absorder => dm.absorder+1).first.try(:name)
```

...

```
<% @dimension_members.each do |dm| %>
    <p><%= dm.name %></p>
    <p><%= DimensionMember.where(:absorder => dm.absorder+1).first.try(:name) %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the next element of an array using `next`:

```
<% @dimension_members.each_with_index do |dm, index| %>
    <p><%= dm.name %></p>
    <p><%= @dimension_members[index + 1].name %></p>
<% end %>
```

Is this what you are looking for, or is `@dimension_members` not already sorted by this "absorder" property? If not, perhaps you should sort it before you iterate.

Comment: I have the @dimensions_members sorted like this in my dimensions model: `has_many :dimension_members, :through => :dimension_versions, :order => 'absorder'` So if they're presorted, next will be defined by that order specification?

Comment: Using dm.next.name returns the error: `undefined method 'next' for #<DimensionMember:0x3f8eb90>`.

Comment: That results in this error: `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`